# Is there a list of java annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, java-annotations

I have been a C++ and Javascript programmer.  Now I am working in Java, Java Spring, and Java Springboot.

Whenever I read Java code in a book or an article, I get thrown by an annotation.  There seem to be hundreds of them!  I have found documentation for particular annotations, but just embedded in the text.  It takes a long time to hunt down each annotation.

Is there a list somewhere of all (or "all" as of a couple years ago) Java annotations?  I would benefit by a couple of lines explanation beside each annotation.

Comment: Everybody can create it's own annotation, so there is not a list of all annotations.

Comment: You could start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html

Comment: Hi, Johannes.  I can make my own annotations, and I understand the seven or so that comes with Java itself.  It seems like a list of a hundred or so would cover most of the ones I encounter.  But I haven't encountered such a list.  (Hibernate has its own annotations, Junit has its own annotations, . . . )

Comment: For Hibernate, look here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a list somewhere of all (or "all" as of a couple years ago)
>   Java annotations?

**I am assuming you are talking about Spring/Spring-Boot annotation.**

There is no suck link available which has all the available annotations.

However, I there are some links that would be helpful for you getting started.

- [javacodegeeks](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/java-annotations-tutorial.html)
- [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/articles/springbootbasan/)
- [journaldev](https://www.journaldev.com/16966/spring-annotations)
- [java2novice](http://www.java2novice.com/spring-boot/springbootapplication-annotation/)
- [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/a-guide-to-spring-framework-annotations)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mehraj!  I think this, especially the dzone reference, will help a lot.  I also found that this document -- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/java-annotations-tutorial.html -- in combination with following the links out to information about subsystems, helps a lot.  Rick

Comment: @user2171796 Happy to help, however, included your link too in the answer.

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions.

Comment: Raedwald, I don't understand.  The question is off what topic?